# How can I find a table with column of maxlength 256 from a SQL DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the columns of certain tables with maxlength of 256, so is there any easy way for finding the sql tables?

Comment: `sys.tables`, `sys.columns`. These objects are [fully documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME([object_id])
FROM sys.columns C
INNER JOIN sys.types T
    ON c.[system_type_id] = T.[system_type_id]
WHERE T.[name] IN ('VARCHAR', 'CHAR', 'NVARCHAR', 'NCHAR')
    AND C.[max_length] = 256;
```

---

Image you want to update all columns from `NVARCHAR(128)` to `NVARCHAR(256)`. You can use the following script:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(T.[schema_id]) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(T.[object_id]) + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + C.[name] + '] NVARCHAR(512);'
FROM sys.tables T
INNER JOIN sys.columns C
    ON T.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.types TY
    ON c.[system_type_id] = TY.[system_type_id]
WHERE TY.[name] =  'NVARCHAR'
    AND C.[max_length] = 512;
```

Note, that if the column is part of index, it should be dropped first. Then, change the type and re-create the index.

Also, note that the `max_length` is the length in bytes. So, for `VARCHAR(128)` its `128`, but for `NVARCHAR` it is doubled.

Comment: Nice. But OP wants to know what table the column is in as well.

Comment: max_length - maximum length in bytes

Answer (score 1):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to accomplish this

```
SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    DATA_TYPE in ('varchar', 'nvarchar') 
    and CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 256;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know the table to update

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 256
```

but, if you also want to know which column has a length of 256 :

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 256
```